# Inheriting generic interfaces with different generic parameters

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface

I'm not sure if this is just something that I'm not using the right syntax for, or if I'm missing a concept.

So the basic is design is this:

```
public abstract class ListItemModelBase
{
    Guid id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ListModelBase<T> where T : ListItemModelBase
{
    List<T> Items { get; set; }
}

public class OrderListModel : ListModelBase<OrderListItemModel>
{
}
```

This all works fine, but now I want to add some inheritance to the controllers in my MVC project that use this.

So what I wanted to do was

```
public interface IListController<T> where T : ListModelBase<ListItemModelBase>
{
    T GetList(int Page, int ItemsPerPage);
}
```

Then I could do:

```
public class OrderListController : IListController<OrderListModel>, BaseController
{
    public OrderListModel GetList(int Page, int ItemsPerPage)
    {

    }
}
```

But obviously this isn't possible due to the fact that ListModelBase needs to have a generic type applied.

The goal here is to make it so that I can use the IListController interface to mean that I can assume that `controller.GetList(1, 10)` will return me a ListModelBase, then I can subsequently assume that The model returned will have a an Id on each of the Items in the list part.

Is this possible? or is there a better way of doing what I want to do?

UPDATE:

To be clear, I know that I can define multiple types at the controller level, but that isn't what I want.

So I know I can do this:

```
public interface IListController<T, TItemModel> 
      where T : ListModelBase<TListModel>
      where TItemModel : ListItemModelBase
{
    T GetList(int Page, int ItemsPerPage);
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted? It compiles fine for me (when I add a dummy `OrderListItemModel` which extends `ListItemModelBase`). Including the bit under "what I wanted to do was...". I'm not entirely clear what you're asking.

Comment: @dvnrrs There error is in the controller implementation, it expects that the `ListModel` is exactly `ListModelBase<ListItemModelBase>` not any derived items from `ListItemModelBase`.

Comment: @mhoff Happy to see an example if it achieves the goal, no idea what covariance is or how it can be used to get what I want.

Comment: I see... is [covariance/contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx) what you're after (the `in`/`out` keywords)? These are used by e.g. `List<T>` so that a `List<T>` is convertible to `List<V>` if `V : T`.

Comment: could either of you provide an example of how convariance could be used in this scenario?

Comment: @dvnrrs `List<T>` is not variant. There is no way to get variant, strongly typed collection with `Add` method.

Comment: So no way to do what I want?

Comment: @Martin: I'd say if you need something and can't get it from somewhere else, you should consider making it. The fact that `List<T>` can't do the job doesn't mean you can't create a variant list.

Comment: @Magus I can move away from `List<T>`, but I'm trying to work out how to define the interface in the way I want... is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loose the constraint on IListController and do something like (don't expose `List<T>` on an interface if you can make due with a lesser type, like `IEnumerable`):

```
public abstract class ListItemModelBase
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class ListItem : ListItemModelBase
{
}

public abstract class ListModelBase<T> where T : ListItemModelBase
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Items { get; set; }
}

public class OrderListModel : ListModelBase<ListItem>
{
}

public interface IListController<T>
{
    T GetList(int page, int itemsPerPage);
}

public abstract class BaseController
{
}

public class OrderListController : BaseController, IListController<OrderListModel>
{
    public OrderListModel GetList(int page, int itemsPerPage)
    {
        return new OrderListModel();
    }
}
```

Then you can do something like:

```
var controller = new OrderListController();
var orderListModel = controller.GetList(0, 10);
foreach (var kindOfA in orderListModel.Items)
{
    doSomeThing(kindOfA.Id);
}
```

Comment: So there is no way to constrain the `IListController` to only those that are of ListModelBase?

Comment: Sure, like `where T : ListModelBase<ListItemModelBase>`? I think the whole source of confusion in this question is due to bad naming. If you straighten out your class / interfaces names and follow the outline in this answer you'll be fine. Sry for any confusion on my part